# Activity for each exercise in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am Creating an App of Math for kids in `android`.. In my app there is activity for asking questions (`Image` of Any Number like 1,2,3,etc.) and Three options in `Image Button` ([ONE], [TWO], [THREE] and so on) with each pressed button there is a sound also. For each question I created an activity.

Is this a good approach to create an activity for each question? I want the random question what i should do please help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:context="com.example.app.kids.kidsmaths.ExerciseSeven"
   android:background="@drawable/bgn">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ivsz"
        android:src="@drawable/seven"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="153dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ib71"
        android:background="@drawable/six2"
        android:src="@drawable/answer_click_wrong"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ib73"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ib73" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ib72"
        android:src="@drawable/answer_click_wrong"
        android:background="@drawable/two2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivsz"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageButton

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ib73"
        android:background="@drawable/seven2"
        android:src="@drawable/answer_click_correct"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ib72"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ib72" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity

```
package com.example.app.kids.kidsmaths;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ExerciseSeven extends AppCompatActivity {
     MediaPlayer music71, music72, music73, music74;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise_seven);
        final ImageView zoom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivsz);
        final Animation zoomAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoomseven);
        zoom.startAnimation(zoomAnimation);
        ImageButton im1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib71);
        ImageButton im2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib72);
        ImageButton im3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib73);
        music71= MediaPlayer.create(ExerciseSeven.this,R.raw.which_number);
        music72= MediaPlayer.create(ExerciseSeven.this,R.raw.wrong);
        music73= MediaPlayer.create(ExerciseSeven.this,R.raw.correct);
        music74= MediaPlayer.create(ExerciseSeven.this,R.raw.wrong2);
        music71.start();
        im1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                music74.start();
            }
        });
        im2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                music72.start();
            }
        });
        im3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Thread timer = new  Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        try {
                            sleep(2000);

                        }catch (InterruptedException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }finally {
                            Intent i = new Intent(ExerciseSeven.this, ExerciseFour.class);
                            startActivity(i);

                        }

                    }
                };
                timer.start();

                music73.start();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        music71.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do all questions "appear" the exact same? If yes, then one activity and simply reload the view with new data

Comment: Maybe you can be more specific on the requirements of your application ?  Does the buttons redirect to questions or exercises ?

Comment: better use viewpager and take dynamic widgets. it will be easy

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is a very bad approach.. You just need to create one activity and pass your variables to it through intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
// question is a custom object that implements Serializable
// if you don't wanna create custom class you can just pass your variables as Strings or so..
intent.putExtra("question", question);
startActivity(intent);
```

and get that in your activity's onCreate:

```
Question question = (Question) getIntent().getExtras().get("question");
```

then set your views to have the values of your question

Answer (score 0):

Activities are heavy object you definitely should not use activities for questions as loading lots of activities will make your app run out of memory.
Instead you can use ViewPager to display questions.  How to use viewpager for slide can found here

https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

You can find solution best fit for your need here

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-ui-workshop-build-an-interactive-quiz-app--mobile-14208